# Is there any difference between "and" and "&&" operators in PHP?

Tags: php

I have the following code and don't think *and* is needed, i.e. `&&` should be used, as there is nothing to assign the left part to?

```
if($_REQUEST['foo'] != 'abc' and $_REQUEST['bar'] == 'def')
{
    echo "all your base";
}
```

So it should be:

```
if($_REQUEST['foo'] != 'abc' && $_REQUEST['bar'] == 'def')
{
    echo "all your base";
}
```

Comment: *(related)* [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: *(reference)* [Operator Precedence in the PHP Language](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, `&&` and `and` do the same thing, but take a look at the [operator precedence](http://de3.php.net/language.operators.precedence). You can see that `&&` and `and` are not on the same level, so mixing that could give you unexpected results in some cases - I recommend always using `&&`, but that's your choice.

Comment: yes, i this case i think && is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

&& and "and" are two different things, because of their precedence.

> The reason for the two different variations of "and" and "or" operators is that they operate at different precedences. (See Operator Precedence.)

- See *[Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)*
- And *[Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)*

Answer (score 2):

'and' and '&&' is the same operator, apart from precedence differences.

They are *different* operators, but they operate the same, apart from precedence differences.

Comment: also, using '&&' makes you look cooler.

Comment: Not true. `and` is `T_LOGICAL_AND` while `&&` is `T_BOOLEAN_AND`. See http://de2.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

Comment: Hm, did not know this. What does this imply? Their both logical operators, but different tokens. What does that really mean? :)

Comment: it means they are not the **same** operator ;) If they were, they wouldn't have different precedence.

Comment: Ah, yes, that was just a bad choice of words :) I'll edit...